# javascript external file - call function fail

Tags: php, javascript, apache

i just can't figure out this one.
this is the web page file: http://lookaroundyou.net/test.php
click on button and nothing happens.

i use same files on my localhost computer and alert pop ups? why? please

accessing ajax.js directly gives me forbidden message so i suppose it has something to do with permissions? how to alte this?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is permissions here, when trying to load your `ajax.js` file I'm getting a 403-Forbidden, so the script never loads for my browser...which is what's causing the error.

Your page is at the root of the domain, so this doesn't make much sense:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  language="javascript" src="../ajax.js">
```

...that `../` shouldn't be there (it would be beneath the root of the site), make sure your path to `ajax.js` is correct.

Comment: ok. i've changed path to the file but same again. don't have much experience with uploading files on webservers so any other tip i would prefer in more how to details. thanks

Comment: @daniel - it's still a permissions issue, see what happens when you try and access it directly? http://lookaroundyou.net/class/ajax.js

Comment: it is a permisson issue again

Comment: how do i alter this permission issue?

Comment: @daniel - I have no idea what server you're using...I'd ask a question specifically tagged `php` and whatever platform you're using...the answer will vary depending on the server, e.g. apache vs iis, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Failed to load source for: http://lookaroundyou.net/ajax.js

Answer (score 0):

http://lookaroundyou.net/ajax.js gives a 403 Forbidden HTTP status and the JavaScript file is not included. Check your server settings and/or .htaccess files.

Also why include `../ajax.js` if you're already at the top level? It should be just `ajax.js`. But note that this is not the reason your script doesn't work because the browser is smart enough to look in the right place even with those extra `..`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, loading http://lookaroundyou.net/ajax.js isn't allowed on your server.

Maybe, it's in the wrong place since you're trying to load it via "`../ajax.js`" which means in the folder before your web folder, or totally absent.